# how can I call to a property of an array from another file

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to call from a HTML file using the script tag to a javascript file which is an array, and I want to call to a property on the array.

```
editor.service('pk7Data', function () {

    this.pokemonList = [
        {
        index: 0,
        pokedex: 0,
        name: 'None'
        },
        {
        index: 1,
        pokedex: 1,
        name: 'Bulbasaur'
        },
        {
        index: 2,
        pokedex: 2,
        name: 'Ivysaur'
        },
        {
        index: 3,
        pokedex: 3,
        name: 'Venusaur'
        }
```

I want to call to the `name` property from an HTML script. How can I do it?

Comment: *call to the "name" property from an html script* ... theres no property from an html(?) script(?) , and youre not able to call a string...

Comment: I'm sure OP wants to retrieve the value of a property of one of the array elements.

Comment: If this script executes after the inline HTML script, you can define the name as a global variable within the inline script, which will then make it accessible from the separate script. It's best practice to limit the use of global variables, though. I'd recommend removing the inline script and making your code more modular.

Comment: If you expect someone to spend his time analyzing your problem. please also take your time reading first [ask] and them asking your question accordingly, preferably supplying [mcve]. Now it is incomplete and hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? **UPDATED the JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/qtjr6oqc/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log(externalFunc.getPokemonList());
  $.each(externalFunc.getPokemonList(), function(k, v) {
    $('#list').append('<option value="' + v.name + '">' + v.name + '</option>');
  });
  $('#list').on('change', function(e) {
    var name = $(this).val();
    if (name === "None") {
      $('#name').text("");
      $('#img').attr('src', "");
      return;
    }
    var pokeObj = externalFunc.getPokemonByName(name);
    if(typeof pokeObj == "object") {
      $('#name').text(pokeObj.name);
      $('#img').attr('src', pokeObj.img);
    }
  });
});

//
//alert(JSON.stringify(externalFunc.getPokemonByName("Bulbasaur")));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // PUT THIS CODE IN AN EXTERNAL JS file and 
  // and add the source in the html like:
  // <script type="text/javascript" src="external.js">
  var externalFunc = (function() {

    var list_ = [{
      "index": 0,
      "pokedex": 0,
      "name": "None"
    }, {
      "index": 1,
      "pokedex": 1,
      "name": "Bulbasaur",
      "img": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/96/d2/1d/96d21d738561947f96255e6f12f1754a.png"
    }, {
      "index": 2,
      "pokedex": 2,
      "name": "Ivysaur",
      "img": "http://cartoonbros.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Ivysaur-1.gif"
    }, {
      "index": 3,
      "pokedex": 3,
      "name": "Venusaur",
      "img": "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/b/b2/003Venusaur_Dream.png/revision/latest?cb=20140908150056"
    }];

    var getPokemonByName = function(name) {
      if (name == null) {
        return "";
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < list_.length; i++) {
        var pokeObj = list_[i];
        if (pokeObj.name === name) {
          return pokeObj;
        }
      }
      return "";
    };

    var getPokemonList = function() {
      return list_;
    };

    var obj = {
      getPokemonByName: getPokemonByName,
      getPokemonList: getPokemonList
    };

    return obj;
  })();
</script>
<select name="list" id="list">
</select>
<p>
  <span id="name"></span><br/>
  <span id="pic"><img src="" id="img" style="width:50px;height:50px;border:0px;"/></span>
</p>
```

Comment: no, I will explain it better, i'm using this array on an html select tag, and it works as I want, I have also an image depending on what option the select tag has, and it displays the image that corresponds to the item by using an span tag. Now, I want to make a blob file and I want to make the name of the file with the array, using the "name" on the array, but I don't know how

Comment: So, when you say blob, do you mean an external JS file that contains the array?..

Comment: I've updated the jsFiddle, please see if this is what you're looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I like the pictures you collected for your little demo :-)  +1!